# Time-Series Forecast where the data is a random variable itself?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, distributions, forecasting

I have one concern regarding a time series forecast.
I have panel data from which I computed the monthly mean. These monthly variables  are now itself random and have a relatively high standard error and weird distrubtion (basically uniform)

Now I'm wondering, what method I could apply in order to predict the macroeconomic influence on that time series?
Are there any specific models or even machine learning methods in order to Analyse my model?
Thanks,

Konstantin

Comment: Yes, Time-Series Forecast where the data is a random variable itself, because it's a function of random data.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good place to use a Hidden Markov Model, the best Python tutorial for which I have found [here](http://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html).  The distribution of your inputs shouldn't be an issue with HMM.